# Erweiterter Infinitiv, Komma vor "und"

Tags: conjunction, infinitive, comma

Mein (gekürzter) Satz lautet:

```
Ich hoffe, bei dieser Arbeit meine Fähigkeiten einbringen zu können(,) und durch Erfahrung und Motivation einen Beruf auszuüben, der mir gefällt.
```

Diesen Satz mit noch mehr Nebensätzen und Adjektiven, die ich zur Übersichtlichkeit entfernt habe, möchte ich in einem Bewerbungsschreiben einbringen. (Auf das Thema, dass zu lange Sätze unattraktiv in Bewerbungsschreiben wirken, möchte ich hier nicht eingehen.)

**Frage 1:** Wird an der eingeklammerten Stelle im Satz ein Komma gesetzt? Es sind schließlich zwei verschiedene erweiterte Infinitive, und der erste endet vor dem "und".

Zudem habe ich eine weitere Frage. Falls sich bei Frage 1 herausstellt, dass kein Komma gesetzt wird, wird in dem folgenden Fall dennoch ein Komma gesetzt?

```
Er läuft, um Spaß zu haben, und trägt dabei eine Jacke.
```

**Frage 2:** Wird das zweite Komma gesetzt?

An dieser Stelle kommt nach dem "und" kein weiterer erweiterter Infinitiv, sondern der Hauptsatz geht weiter. Dieses Komma würde ich definitiv setzen wollen, jedoch finde ich nicht einmal hierzu klare Regeln online.

Comment: Willkommen bei German SX! »Auf das Thema, dass zu lange Sätze unattraktiv in Bewerbungsschreiben wirken, möchte ich hier nicht eingehen.« Trotzdem möchte ich darauf hinweisen, dass zu lange Sätze unattraktiv in Berwerbungsschreiben wirken ;-)

Comment: Der Ausdruck "durch Erfahrung und Motivation einen Beruf auszuüben" klingt für mich nicht sinnvoll. "Ich übe meinen Beruf durch Erfahrung und Motivation aus"?

Comment: Danke für das Feedback, aber der Satz entspricht  ohnehin nicht dem Original, und ich werde noch überlegen, ob oder wie ich ihn ändere. Meine Frage bezieht sich nicht darauf, ob der Satz inhaltlich sinnvoll wäre, sondern ob die Grammatik korrekt ist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Antwort 1**: Es wird kein Komma gesetzt, da es sich hier um zwei gleichwertige Nebensätze handelt. Technisch gesehen sind es zwar zwei Infinitivgruppen, da diese aber funktional wie ein Nebensatz eingesetzt werden, werden sie im Sinne der Kommasetzung auch als solche behandelt.

Um zu Testen, ob zwei Nebensätze gleichwertig sind, kann man versuchen einen der beiden wegzulassen. Erscheint der Satz dann immer noch sinnvoll, werden sie durch ein Komma getrennt, außer sie werden durch ein Bindewort (z.B. *und*) miteinander verbunden.

**Antwort 2**: Hier werden die Kommata gesetzt. Die beiden Hauptsätze sind durch das Wort *und* verbunden und werden daher nicht durch ein Komma getrennt. Die Infinitivgruppe (wieder in der Rolle eines Nebensatzes) ist hier ein Einschub, der durch ein Komma am Anfang und Ende abgetrennt werden muss. Daher steht das Komma nicht für die Trennung der Hauptsätze, aber für die Trennung des Einschubs.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Das entspricht auch dem, das ich inzwischen erwartet habe. Ist ein Komma im ersten Satz aber nun ausgeschlossen, oder ist es nur unüblich wie beispielsweise zwischen zwei Hauptsätzen?

Comment: So ein Link würde mich auch sehr interessieren.

Comment: Meine Antwort folgt dem Regelwerk des [Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung). Die wichtigen Paragraphen sind § 72 (gleichrangige Teilsätze mit und), § 74 (Nebensätze) und § 75 (Infinitivgruppen).

Comment: @QueensKnight Danke! Ich denke, es würde Deine Antwort abrunden, wenn Du die Referenz mit einbaust.

Comment: Auch von mir noch einmal danke.